# HTML Page Source not like Output

Tags: php, jquery, html, htmlspecialchars

Am Using a Cron Job (Php script) to extract the loto results on the day of the draw from:

http://www.millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/_cs_sayisal.php

the script i am using is by reading the file, then breaking it into lines to find the numbers:
as below:

```
$rfile = "http://www.millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/_cs_sayisal.php";
$lines = file($rfile);  

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " .htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

The Surprise is that the output of the page (That you see online) is not like the source (When PHP read the file)!!

I tried "Select all" by mouse, and reading "View Selection Source {Firefox}) it worked.

But I need it done by Cron Job.

How can I read the source? it seems the code is hidden using jquery.

Comment: I really do not get, what you want to achive. For me, this script is print the source of the page: `Line #0 :
Line #1 : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> `

Comment: Please check the source, it is not like the output!

Comment: PHP source can't be fetched at all and thus getting html document only

Comment: PHP is reading the source of the page, THIS IS THE PROBLEM, as the source is different than the output

Comment: The actual data is gathered from http://www.millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/cekilisler/sayisal/20141115.json which seems in the format [year][month][day].json good luck with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual data is gathered from http://www.millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/cekilisler/sayisal/20141115.json which seems in the format [year][month][day].json

You can use `json_decode` in php to get an array with values, which you can then use to do whatever you want.

If you want to see all available data you could do the following:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/cekilisler/sayisal/20141115.json");
$json = json_decode($content);
echo "<pre>";    
var_dump($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the page is being built by Javascript.  When you're saying you're looking at the source, you're actually looking at the DOM tree.  If you look at the source (command/control-U), you'll see what I mean.  To get to the data, you have two options.

1) Try to reverse engineer the Javascript and see where it's getting the data from that it's using to propagate the site.

or

2) Use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) to build the site DOM for you, and then you can crawl that instead.

Comment: Can t PHP read the output as TEXT not the source, as I have no idea about PhantomJS.

Comment: Turn Javascript off on your browser and then go to the lotto page.  You'll see that the lotto numbers are blank.  That's what PHP would see.  That's because the numbers are not in that page, but rather inserted dynamically with Javascript after the page loads.